# AEM OSGI Bundle for MSSQL - error javax.net.SocketFactory classdefnotfound

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, mssql-jdbc, aem-6

I am trying to create an OSGI bundle for MSSQL driver.  I'll post my Manifest below.

Basically, I get an error javax.net.SocketFactory no class def found.

I am able to upload the bundle and start it but, fails when trying to use the a datasource.

Here is my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Jdbc
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.s360g.mssql.jdbc
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Automatic-Module-Name: com.s360g.mssql.jdbc
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Export-Package: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc,
 microsoft.sql
Import-Package: javax.naming,
 javax.naming.spi,
 javax.net,
 javax.net.ssl,
 javax.security.auth,
 javax.security.auth.login,
 javax.security.auth.x500,
 javax.sql,
 javax.transaction.xa,
 javax.xml.parsers,
 javax.xml.stream,
 javax.xml.transform,
 javax.xml.transform.dom,
 javax.xml.transform.sax,
 javax.xml.transform.stax,
 javax.xml.transform.stream,
 org.ietf.jgss,
 org.w3c.dom,
 org.xml.sax,
 org.xml.sax.helpers
```

```
com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException: Process execution resulted in an error
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.HandlerBase.executeProcess(HandlerBase.java:201) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0016]
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:260) [com.adobe.granite.workflow.core:2.0.240.CQ650-B0016]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.JobConsumerManager$JobConsumerWrapper.process(JobConsumerManager.java:502) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.startJob(JobQueueImpl.java:293) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.access$100(JobQueueImpl.java:60) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl$1.run(JobQueueImpl.java:229) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/SocketFactory
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.getSocketFactory(IOBuffer.java:2636)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.getConnectedSocket(IOBuffer.java:2687)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.getDefaultSocket(IOBuffer.java:2674)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2358)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:672)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2747)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291)[!
```

[Bundle information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAqgh.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAqgh.png)

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more details e.g. which version of mssql driver you use? Version 9.2.1 seems to be an OSGi bundle already.

Comment: You are correct.  I don't need to wrap it.  Version 6.2 and up seem to be OSGI enabled.

Comment: Does the original bundle work or you still get `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: Version 9 has some missing dependencies in AEM.  However, I tried 6.2 and it works fine.  I uploaded it "as-is" from my download and it started and became available immediately.  I didn't try any other versions.